# users photos not loading in flutter app interface

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

```
При прохождении этого туториала я столкнулся с проблеммой, не отображаютсяфотографии пользователей 
[https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-a-chat-app-ui-with-flutter/][1]

[![this interface][2]][2]


 [![structure of project][3]][3]


  [1]: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-a-chat-app-ui-with-flutter/
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/32kwA.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km8zp.png
```

> home_page.dart
>
> unmarked files are completely identical with the files from the tutorial

import 'package:app_chat/screens/chat_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      const HomePage({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: const ChatPage(),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey.shade600,
            selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.message),
                label: "Chats",
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.group_work),
                label: "Channels",
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
                label: "Profile",
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

> chat_page.dart

```
        import 'package:app_chat/models/users_model.dart';
    import 'package:app_chat/widgets/conversation_list.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
      const ChatPage({super.key});
    
      @override
      _ChatPageState createState() => _ChatPageState();
    }
```

> user parameters have been changed to those specified in the user model file

```
    class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
      List<ChatUsers> chatUsers = [
        ChatUsers(
            name: "Jane Russel",
            messageText: "Awesome Setup",
            imageURL: "images/userImage1.jpeg",
            time: "Now"),
        ChatUsers(
            name: "Glady's Murphy",
            messageText: "That's Great",
            imageURL: "images/userImage2.jpeg",
            time: "Yesterday"),
        ChatUsers(
            name: "Jorge Henry",
            messageText: "Hey where are you?",
            imageURL: "images/userImage3.jpeg",
            time: "31 Mar"),
        ChatUsers(
            name: "Philip Fox",
            messageText: "Busy! Call me in 20 mins",
            imageURL: "images/userImage4.jpeg",
            time: "28 Mar"),
        ChatUsers(
            name: "Debra Hawkins",
            messageText: "Thankyou, It's awesome",
            imageURL: "images/userImage5.jpeg",
            time: "23 Mar"),
        ChatUsers(
            name: "Jacob Pena",
            messageText: "will update you in evening",
            imageURL: "images/userImage6.jpeg",
            time: "17 Mar"),
        ChatUsers(
            name: "Andrey Jones",
            messageText: "Can you please share the file?",
            imageURL: "images/userImage7.jpeg",
            time: "24 Feb"),
        ChatUsers(
            name: "John Wick",
            messageText: "How are you?",
            imageURL: "images/userImage8.jpeg",
            time: "18 Feb"),
      ];
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SafeArea(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 10),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        const Text(
                          "Conversations",
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 8, right: 8, top: 2, bottom: 2),
                          height: 30,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.2),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            color: Colors.pink[50],
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            children: const <Widget>[
                              Icon(
                                Icons.add,
                                color: Colors.pink,
                                size: 20,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 2,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Add New",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                //Строка поиска
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, left: 16, right: 16),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Search...",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600),
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                        size: 20,
                      ),
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade100)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: chatUsers.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ConversationList(
                      name: chatUsers[index].name,
                      messageText: chatUsers[index].messageText,
                      imageUrl: chatUsers[index].imageURL,
                      time: chatUsers[index].time,
                      isMessageRead: (index == 0 || index == 3) ? true : false,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

> users_model.dart
>
> the names of the parameters have been changed as in the model file

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

```
    class ChatUsers {
      String name;
      String messageText;
      String imageURL;
      String time;
      ChatUsers(
          {required this.name,
          required this.messageText,
          required this.imageURL,
          required this.time});
    }


conversation_list.dart

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ConversationList extends StatefulWidget {
  String name;
  String messageText;
  String imageUrl;
  String time;
  bool isMessageRead;
  ConversationList(
      {super.key, required this.name,
      required this.messageText,
      required this.imageUrl,
      required this.time,
      required this.isMessageRead});
  @override
  _ConversationListState createState() => 
_ConversationListState();
}

class _ConversationListState extends 
 State<ConversationList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, 
 right: 16, top: 10, bottom: 10),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: 
 NetworkImage(widget.imageUrl),
                    maxRadius: 30,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 16,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: 
 CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            widget.name,
                            style: const 
  TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 6,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            widget.messageText,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 13,
                                color: 

     Colors.grey.shade600,
                                    fontWeight: 
   widget.isMessageRead
                                        ? 
 FontWeight.bold
                      

              : FontWeight.normal),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              widget.time,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: widget.isMessageRead
                      ? FontWeight.bold
                      : FontWeight.normal),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> pubspec.yaml

```
    name: app_chat
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.2 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
     - images/userImage1.jpeg
     - images/userImage2.jpeg
     - images/userImage3.jpeg
     - images/userImage4.jpeg
     - images/userImage5.jpeg
     - images/userImage6.jpeg
     - images/userImage7.jpeg
     - images/userImage8.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
```

## For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,

## see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages

Answer (score 0):

I assume you copied your files inside **assets/images/** folder right?

Also you need to reference your images into the **pubspec.yaml** file like this:

```
  flutter:

  ...

    assets:
      - assets/images/example.png
```

Comment: i do this see my pubspec.yaml

Comment: Did you try to simply restarted the Android studio and re-run the app ?